# How to create lists dynamically using for loop in Java

Tags: java

Here's what I am doing:
1. fetch array from server
2. using Asynctask,  I am catching the string in my onPostExecute method
3. iterating through array list and creating the list according to the string values of the array.

But I am getting this error "Variable 'result' is already defined in this scope", i tried searching over the net. But in vain. I don't understand the problem.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        HashMap<String, List<String>> MoviesDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        int count = result.length;
        for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
            List<String> result[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
         }

    }
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Here there is no use of MoviesDetails.

Comment: Rename the variable.

Comment: Accept the aswer if it worked for u

Answer (score 0):

You have String[] result already defined. Change

```
 List<String> result[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to some another variable

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is this:

You have `String[] result` in your arguments. Then you try to define a `List<String> result`. So the compiler complains that you have two variables with same name.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @topsycoder What exactly are you trying to do with your results? :)

Comment: I have an array {"Action_Movies","Romantic_Movies","Horror_Movies","Comedy_Movies"}; I want to create a hashMap with <String, List<String>> where string is going to be types of movies from above array and List<String> is going to be names of movies under a particular type. Since, I am getting this array from servers. I want to make it dynamic. I want to create: List<String> Action_Movies = new ArrayList<String>(); List<String> Romantic_Movies = new ArrayList<String>(); But I want to make it dynamic using for loop

Comment: You need to put it in a hashmap then. Each category of movies mapped to a List.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I am new with android. Could you help me with the code. If say I have a an array like String[] array = {"Action_Movies", "Romantic_Movies", "Love_Movies"}; and I want to initalize Action_Movies as List<String> Action_Movies = new ArrayList<String>(); and same goes with other values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong here:

1. There is already a result variable on the onPostExecute() function. Try renaming your other result variable.
2. You cannot use the [] operator on what you are trying to achieve.

What exactly are you trying to store: A list of strings, or a list of (ArrayList) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    int count = result.length;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        list.add(result[i]);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to create a `List<String> result` variable despite there being a parameter called `result`, so you'll need to rename it. You also need to initialise your list outside of the loop to do what you want, e.g.:

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    resultList.add(result[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to create multiple lists then you'll need to define a collection of type `List<String>`, e.g.:

```
List<List<String>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    resultList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Comment: No you didn't get it. I want to make more than one list, hence I am initalizing it in loop

Comment: @topsycoder updated my answer with what I think you are wanting to do, you might need to be more specific though.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert your String Array to ArrayList using this

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourStringArray))
```

Thanks. Hope it will help.